Is \defcitealias compatible with biblatex?
The biblatex manual says under "3.9.9 natbib Compatibility Command": "Aliasing with
\defcitealias, \citetalias, and \citepalias is possible as well. Note
that the compatibility commands will not emulate the citation format of the natbib
package. They merely alias natbib’s commands to functionally equivalent facilities
of the biblatex package." I wasn't able to replicate that in the example below. Any suggestion, please?
tex:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith2024,
  author = {John Smith},
  title = {An Example Article},
  journal = {Journal of Examples},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {42},
  number = {7},
  pages = {123--456},
  doi = {10.1234/example.2024.42.7.123}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
{\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}}
{}
\makeatother

\defcitealias{smith2024}{primary source}

\begin{document}

The \citetalias{smith2024} says: \dots

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
{\printbibliography}
{%
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
}
\makeatother

\end{document}

terminal:
pdflatex --version | head -n1 # pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
file='/path/name.tex'
find . -type f -name "${file%.tex}.*"\
| grep -v 'tex'\
| while read path; do rm "${path}"; done
pdflatex "$file" 
bibtex "${file%.tex}" # Alternatively: biber
for i in {1..2}; do pdflatex "${file}"; done

In the case of biblatex the first call to pdflatex yields:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \defcitealias
                  {smith2024}{primary source}



\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}

Initially, I thought \defcitealias wasn't working for biblatex. However, as suggested in the comments, using the natbib package option resolves the issue.
